# Ubuntu doesn't calculate expression in [ ..]?

Tags: scripts

I'm a newbie to Linux. I'm reading the book Linux: Rute Users. Everything is good till I come to  Unit 7.1.

My script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter X"
read X
echo "enter Y"
read Y
echo "X*Y = $X*$Y = $[X*Y] = $[$X*$Y]"
```

My terminal does not give me X*Y = 2*3 = 6, instead it prints

```
X*Y = 2*3 = $[X*Y] = $[2*3]
```

I also tried the command in the terminal directly:

```
echo "$[2*3]"
```

and it gives me 6 correctly.

What is the problem with my script? I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS 32bit. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please do not use slang in your questions.

Comment: Edited. Can you help me out of this?

Comment: `X*Y = 12*15 = 180 = 180` is what I get when using 12 and 15.

Comment: Any idea what could possible cause this? Big thanks. Can't move one having this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The ((...)) conditional expression evaluates an arithmetic expression
> like it was written in a "normal" algorithmic language (you can even
> omit dollar signs from the variables) and sets the exit status to 1 if
> the expression evaluates to 0, or to 0 if the expression evaluates to
> a non-zero value.
>
> In bash version 3.2 and later you can (and should) use $(( ))

Quote from [this](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml)

What is bash?

> Descended from the Bourne Shell, Bash is a GNU product, the "Bourne
> Again SHell." It's the standard command line interface on most Linux
> machines. It excels at interactivity, supporting command line editing,
> completion, and recall. It also supports configurable prompts - most
> people realize this, but don't know how much can be done.

You should use `(( ))` for math expressions:

```
echo "$(( 2*3 ))"
```

or

```
echo "$(( $X*$Y ))"
```

or even

```
echo "$(( X*Y ))"
```

---

**Why does `echo $[..]` also works in some environment?**

> **Arithmetic Expansion**
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic
> expression and the substitution of the result. The format for
> arithmetic expansion is:
>
> $((expression))
>
> The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed
> in upcoming versions of bash.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves my problem, so echo $[<expr>] won't work on 12.04?

Comment: It is not restriction of Ubuntu version. It is `bash` way of arithmetic expression. It was added in `bash` version 3.2. In Ubuntu 12.04 `bash` version is 4.2. It will also work

Comment: Thanks. but why does it echo $[..] works as a single line command, just doesn't work in a shell script?

Comment: May be you made a mistake in your shell script? Can you paste it somewhere, I will check it. I add information about `echo $[..]` to answer

Comment: I've already pasted it above in the original question. Anything wrong with that script? And thanks for the additional info.